# How can I calculate the difference between two times in 24h format using Java?

Tags: java, time

How can I calculate the difference between two times in 24h format using Java? I'm loading the times from a file. Times are saved as `int`s, for example: 19 45 06 34 (the first two digits represent the first time; the second two, the second time). How can I calculate the difference between them and print it in the format `??h ??m`? For example, the times above should show 10h 49m.

OK... I'm really a beginner and this is an assignment, I know it's not useful. Let's say I have something like this saved in my file:
"SO35 13 56 05 26" — (first is code of the whatever, and the two times)

I don't even know how to load it from the file and then calculate it. That code is for picking up which time to calculate. Inside the file, there are 24 lines similar to the one I put here.

Answer (score 7):

Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net)

- Split the string up into two
- Parse them using a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) (ideally into a `LocalTime`)
- Get the difference between them using `new Period(from, to, PeriodType.minutes().withHours())`

Comment: +1  Don't get the downvote. While it's a third party library, I think Joda Time is essential if you have to do any sort of date/time manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize two Date objects and then input the values of the two times.
Then you can just convert that to milliseconds format and subtract them.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably convert them into Date objects, subtract the dates (they will equate to "Long" milisecond counts) then convert that back into the format you want.

Be careful if you span day boundaries-since your dates don't include day boundaries this sounds pretty useless--homework assignment or something?

Comment: yes assignment and I'm really begginer so I don't really understant all that you r writing here to me...I can't use it. I have no idea how to use it. :(

Comment: Bill K probably means "millisecond" counts. i.e. each Date object internally stores a moment in time as a long which count as milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is so simple, you may as well convert both times to minutes, subtract the difference and convert to hours/minutes.

```
Scanner s
int diff = Math.abs(s.nextInt()*60 + s.nextInt() - s.nextInt()*60 - s.nextInt());
System.out.println(diff / 60 + "h " + diff % 60 + "m");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that these two times are from time - to time?
i.e. the difference between 7:45pm to 6:34am the following day?
Because that would be different than 6:34am to 7:45pm.
(Something you are going to have to keep in mind.)
What I would advise you to do (if you don't want to use Joda Time) is to look at using the `SimpleDateFormat` class and `Calendar` class.
To get the exact difference in *milliseconds* you use a `Date` object and the `getTime` method. You can then divide by the number of millisecs in an hour then by the number of millesecs in a minute.

See:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any libraries to do this. Just solve it like you would on paper

```
  HH MM
  06 34
- 19 45
--------
  10 49
```

You can't subtract 34 from 45 because 34 is smaller than 45, so you "borrow" 60 minutes from the hours. You end up with (60+34)-45 = 49 and the hours get reduced from 6 to 5. Since the 5 is less than 19, we assume that we have crossed into the next day and so the difference in hours is 5+(24-19)=10.

Here is what the code would look like:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String filename = "myfile.txt";
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line;

        //read the file, line-by-line
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

            //break the line into various pieces
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
            scanner.next(); //skip the first bit
            int hour1 = scanner.nextInt();
            int min1 = scanner.nextInt();
            int hour2 = scanner.nextInt();
            int min2 = scanner.nextInt();

            int diffMin;
            if (min2 < min1) {
                // borrow 60mins from the hours
                diffMin = 60 + min2 - min1;
                if (hour2 == 0) {
                    hour2 = 23;
                } else {
                    hour2--;
                }
            } else {
                diffMin = min2 - min1;
            }

            int diffHour;
            if (hour2 < hour1) {
                diffHour = hour2 + 24 - hour1;
            } else {
                diffHour = hour2 - hour1;
            }
            System.out.printf("%sh %sm\n", diffHour, diffMin);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This code could be compacted, but I have made it verbose so that you understand what is happening.

Comment: I can't make it work can you please again look at my problem, I did put some new info, maybe you will know some solution. Thank you...

Comment: Even if you don't *need* any libraries, they sure as heck make life simpler, IMO.